# Why won't my computer connect to wireless?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, internet-connection

Why can't I connect to the Internet wirelessly? I confirmed that all of my router information is correct and have tried this several times, but my computer still wont connect to the Internet via my wireless network.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command:

```
rfkill unblock all
```